# Getting "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" error

Tags: python, spyder

No code will run through Spyder at the moment. It runs at Python 3.7.

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 279, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 1, in 
a#
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

This is the full error message I am getting and have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Please provide python code snippet also.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems you somehow wrote and corrupted the file `spydercustomize.py`, which belongs to one of our most important packages. So now you have to reinstall Anaconda, sorry.